# Freegate in ubuntu

Tags: proxy

It's possible to use Freegate (for surfing the web anonymously)in Ubuntu 13.04? Is it possible to use Wine for this purpose? Would it work really?

Comment: Have a look at FoxyProxy.

Comment: Try a VPN: http://www.vpnbook.com/howto/setup-openvpn-on-ubuntu

Comment: Try [DNScrypt](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/encrypt-dns-traffic-in-linux-with.html)

Comment: Yes, freegate works fine under Wine. I ran it some time ago. Though you may have to download a .dll file.

Answer (score 4):

Why use wine when you have a native app for that? Based on Firefox...

## [Tor (anonymity network)](https://www.torproject.org/index.html.en)

[image: tor-browser-3.5]

> [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/index.html.en) is free software and an open network that helps you defend
>   against traffic analysis, a form of network surveillance that
>   threatens personal freedom and privacy, confidential business
>   activities and relationships, and state security.

For installation in Ubuntu via the [tor-browser ppa](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/tor-browser), copy paste the following in your terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```

**Supported distributions**

Trusty (14.04), Saucy (13.10), Raring (13.04), Quantal(12.10), Precise (12.04).

Further information can be found in there wiki: [Tor (anonymity network)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29)

---

**Source**:

- [PPA Updates: Tor Browser Bundle 3.5, Sublime Text 3 Beta Build 3059 ~ Web Upd8: Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/12/ppa-updates-tor-browser-bundle-35.html)

---

**Further reading**

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983/36315)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629/36315)
- [Is there any guarantee that software from Launchpad PPAs is free from viruses and backdoor threats?](https://askubuntu.com/q/7662/36315)

Answer (score 3):

Its possible, follow the instruction:

1. install latest version of wine:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wine
   ```
2. install winetricks:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install winetricks
   ```
3. Install the MFC 4.2 library into your Wine home:

   ```
   winetricks mfc42
   ```
4. copy the freegate executable to `~/.wine/drive_c/`.
5. open the freegate executable with wine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
I have helped configure freegate/tor/yourfreedom/... for linux (Ubuntu, Fedora).

Easiest way would be using wine, and a browser with a proxy-switcher add-on, so that you can switch between different proxies easily.

Chrome/Chromium with proxy switchysharp. 
Firefox with foxyproxy (basic or standard)

With yourfreedom you wouldn't need wine, cause it can run on java VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tor-browser`.

`Tor-browser` is a `firefox` base browser that you can go through filter web sites.

download link: [torproject.org: Download Tor](https://torproject.org/download)

Answer (score 0):

yeah just install tor -browser and you'll get out of that zone.

```
sudo apt-get install tor torsocks
```

or visit their [website](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en) and unpack it, then run the script called `start*.sh`. Good luck man but you'll have to give some permissions first.

Answer (score 0):

I got an error message saying `gdiplus.dll` was missing; to get Freegate to run I also needed to do: `$ winetricks gdiplus`

But by default Wine wgets the (538mb) Win7 SP1 from Microsoft just for this 1.6mb dll. This might be slow/painful if local internet is slow/unreliable.

There are download sites for individual dlls - not sure which are trustworthy of the security implications, if any. But it looks like copying gdiplus.dll into

```
~/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/system32/
```

would do the trick. (`$ winetricks gdiplus` might also be necessary.)

(Also if you do the big SP1 file `windows6.1-KB976932-X86.exe` gets stored in `~/.cache/winetricks/win7sp1/` & apparently isn't needed unless is happens to contain a dll required by another app. I deleted it :)