# How to search for an official PPA?

Tags: ppa, repository, versions

Some applications in Ubuntu don't update automatically, for example VirtualBox, GCC and Git.

I'm afraid of using unofficial PPAs, but I can't find PPAs from official sources.

Comment: I upvoted and favorited this question because it is global for PPA users. Maybe it is a start point for a program such as **apt-cache search** but for PPA.

Answer (score 5):

**For Finding PPA**:

- Visit [Launchpad **Personal Package Archives for Ubuntu**](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas)
- Visit [ubuntu updates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas)
  and search with **"Package Search"** then find appropriate package
  according to your version of Ubuntu.
- For Browsing all PPAs, visit : [PPA
  List](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppas)

---

For getting Information about PPA and use, visit:

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983/256099)
- [Repositories/Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

From [community PPA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PPA):

> Security
>
> PPAs have not undergone the same process of validation as regular
>   ubuntu packages. End users install PPAs at their own risk. Although
>   each key is cryptographically signed, in order to confirm an uploader,
>   keys are not matched to specific individuals, except via their
>   "launchpad" accounts.
>
> Subsequently, installing a PPA should be considered to be a
>   low-security alternative as compared to the main repository, but
>   marginally higher security than simply installing software at random
>   from the internet. As part of adding a PPA, you trust the developer to
>   not only install packages, but also to allow them to provide ongoing
>   updates.

---

Following also may help you:

- [Are PPAs safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629)
- [Is there any guarantee that software from Launchpad PPAs is free from viruses and backdoor threats?](https://askubuntu.com/q/7662)

Comment: I upvoted this answer. This answer is good because it has clear pointer entences

Answer (score 1):

https://launchpad.net/ seems to host all of the PPAs. You can search for it [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu) (or [here](https://launchpad.net/+search?field.text=)) to find various PPAs - e.g:

- [Virtualbox](https://launchpad.net/virtualbox)
- [Git](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

The problem here is finding out if the PPA is official, or just someone's personal PPA.

For the possible security concerns, you may want to read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo)